# Как лучше обновлять UI элементы в iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Добрый день! Я использую `UITabBarController`, поверх третьего `tabBar` я наложил кнопку, так как мне нужно было чтобы центральный элемент был круглый, на кнопку добавлен элемент `UIImageView`, так ниже кнопки я имею `UILabel`, `UILabel` использую для отображения времени с таймера. У меня есть менеджер который получает данные с сервера, и когда приходит новое изображение я должен его менять в `UIImageView`. На данный момент, я сделал `UIImageView` как глобальную переменную, все работает, но мне данный подход не нравится, как можно сделать лучше?

**Обновлено**: На данный момент я сделал UI элементы в менеджере.

```
class MainBarControllerManager {

    static var lifelineButton = UIButton()
    static var lifelineTimeLabel = UILabel()
    static var lifelineImageView = UIImageView()
}
```

Затем я добавляю их в `UITabBarController`

```
    class MainBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, MainBarControllerDelegate, LifelineManagerDelegate {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUISettings()
        setSettings()

        // lifeline
        setLifelineButton()
        setTimeLabel()
        setCircleTabBarProgressView()

        setDelegates()

        // different setings 
        setImageViewsSettings()

        LifelineManager.instance.getActiveLifeline()
    }

    // MARK: Lifeline elements

    private func setLifelineButton() {
        view.addSubview(MainBarControllerManager.lifelineButton)
        MainBarControllerManager.lifelineButton.addSubview(MainBarControllerManager.lifelineImageView)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    private func setTimeLabel() {
        view.addSubview(MainBarControllerManager.lifelineTimeLabel)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    // MARK: - life line manager delegate

    func updatedLifelineData() {

    }

}
```

В LifelineManager при получение данных я вызываю функцию из MainBarControllerManager для обновление данных в элементах

```
class LifelineManager {
       func getActiveLifeline() {        
    LifelineAPIManager.instance.getActiveLifeline({ (activeLifeline) in

        // Update ui elements
        MainBarControllerManager.updatedUIInformation()

        self.delegate?.updatedLifelineData?()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}

}
```

В MainBarControllerManager обновляю данных в элементах следующим образом

```
    class MainBarControllerManager {
    static func updatedUIInformation() {
        if let productImagePath = LifelineManager.instance.activeLifeline.product?.picture?.path {
            if let url = NSURL(string: productImagePath) {
                lifelineImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(url)
            }
        }

        //
        updateTimer()
    }
}
```

Хоть это работает нормально, мне все равно не нравится мой подход, и я бы хотел узнать как можно это сделать лучше.

Comment: Тут есть что то наверх на обычный MVC? менеджер получил - контроллеру передал - вью заапдейтил.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Добрый день, я обновил информацию о своем опросе, так как в комментарии не удобно было все описывать.

Comment: Вопрос понятен, но чтобы ответить надо писать много кода :) в целом идея такая: ваши переменные должны быть не статиками а мемберами MainBarController. Он же может создавать и класс, который тянет данные из интернета и держать референс на него. После этого вам надо по мере получения данных, отдавать из из модели в контроллер, чтобы он апдейтил вью. Передача данных обычными способами: delegate, block, notification, KVO. если не лень разбираться то любой reactive вам улучшит жизнь в долгосрочной перспективе.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Спасибо за ответ! Если хотите то оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос понятен, но чтобы ответить надо писать много кода :) в целом идея такая: ваши переменные должны быть не статиками а мемберами MainBarController. Он же может создавать и класс, который тянет данные из интернета и держать референс на него. После этого вам надо по мере получения данных, отдавать из из модели в контроллер, чтобы он апдейтил вью. Передача данных обычными способами: delegate, block, notification, KVO. если не лень разбираться то любой reactive вам улучшит жизнь в долгосрочной перспективе.

Answer (score 0):

Если картинка не должна быть кликабельной или влазит в tabBer, то кладешь ее как subview на tabBar (если не влазит, то но не забываешь про tabBar.clipToBounds). Если картинка кликабельная и выше чем tabBar - кладешь на window.

Глобальную переменную можешь вынести в отдельный класс (вместе с UILabel). Можешь добавить их в наследник tabBarController, так правильней, но в целом ничего не поменяется.

Есть варианты с переделыванием всего tabBarController (https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar), но это уже перебор.